# Javascript click button1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, phpbb

I have the following HTML code and I'm trying to make a JavaScript to click on this button

```
<fieldset class="fields1"></fieldset>
<fieldset class="submit-buttons">
<some other button here >
<input class="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" name="post" tabindex="4" accesskey="f"></input>
```

I tried the following lines of code neither of which works:

```
$(".submit-buttons").children('input[name="post"]').click();


$("input[name=post]").click();
```

Is there any other way to click the button1? And is there a way to select the button by its tabindex or accesskey?

Comment: can you share the fiddle for the same

Comment: If you just want to submit the form, you can call `.submit()` on the form item. Modern browsers often won't let you just click buttons with javascript because of possible security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click function is for event handling not triggering events. If you want to trigger a click use trigger

```
$("input[name=post]").trigger('click');
```

Comment: I get this,The submitted form was invalid. Try submitting again.

Comment: what are these comments about? Using the trigger function clicks the button http://plnkr.co/edit/1rbqF2JHUqwmfh0FCPsc?p=preview

Comment: I guess is a website security issue, because doing want i need manually works just fine

Comment: @depperm: I just read the question again. Apologies for confusion. +1

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the close the `<fieldset>` tag

Use following markup

```
  <fieldset class="fields1"></fieldset>
  <fieldset class="submit-buttons">
    <input class="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" name="post" tabindex="4" accesskey="f">
  </fieldset>
```

Also, you would need to add a `event handler` callback inside `click function`

```
$(".submit-buttons").children('input[name="post"]').click(function(){
  alert("clicked")
});
```

and trigger the click event either manually or by jQuery's `trigger()`

```
$("input[name=post]").trigger('click')
```

here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/maOUBbJhYuADCFIcV3Et?p=preview)

Comment: this method already tryied, and
 
I get this,The submitted form was invalid. Try submitting again.

Comment: Can you share a js fiddle or plunkr demonstrating the issue?

Comment: well i'm asking cos i have this issue

Answer (score 0):

First link up any jQuery version and then like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

$("input[name=post]").click(function(){
    alert('dddd');
});
```

if onready click

```
$("input[name=post]").trigger('click');

<form action="#" method="post">
<input class="button1" type="submit" value="Submit" name="post" tabindex="4" accesskey="f"></input>
</form>

start <form> end </form>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmysffgd/1/)

Comment: also on this method 
 
I get this,The submitted form was invalid. Try submitting again.